# Node.JS Embed Client Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, embed

I'm developing an node.js application and i want to "embed" the socket.io client module inside the javascript file. I'm sorry if my explaination is bad, and so i'll take an example.

My code looks like this:

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/ap.js"></script>
```

I want to be like:

```html
<script src="../js/app.js"></script>
```

and not only for socket.io, for all modules that i'll use.

how to do this ? i've tried a lot of things but no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into some technologies for packaging JavaScript code for the browser: bower, browserify, and webpack.